# Can you get special prisoner heads twice in Battle Block Theater?

Tags: battleblock-theater

I started playing Battle Block Theater and have been collecting the special "star" prisoner heads that have been given out. When trading online, there is a huge premium for these characters because their value hasn't been established yet.

I was wondering if you could trade away the character of the week and recollect it again for that week [like playing Furbottom's feature, get and trade away the character, and play it again on insane mode]?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, I recently beated furbuttoms mode and unblocked a hat, someone offered me a toast hat for it so I took the hat, repeated the last level and got it back :)